# Marshalling Struct vs Map in Golang

Tags: json, go, marshalling

Which is better in term of performance or best practice when returning result of JSON, using marshalled `struct` or `map`. I've seen some codes use map and marshal them to be returned as json, others use marshaled struct to return json response.

Example:

Use `struct`:

```
type Response struct {
    A int `json:"a"`
    B string `json:"b"`
}

r := Response{A:1,B:"1"}
resp, _ := json.Marshal(r)
```

Use `map`:

```
m := map[string]interface{}{
    A: 1,
    B: "1",
}
resp, _ := json.Marshal(m)
```

Which is better?

Comment: I saw a benchmark for this some time ago and struct was the more performant option, however the difference might have changed since then, also with struct types there is some caching of marshaling algorithm so if the first run isn't faster, subsequent ones should be. Also Go does have the `testing` package which provides for an easy benchmarking, if you're concerned you should write benchmarks for your types.

Comment: Seems like struct is more performant in benchmarks. See the benchmark https://play.golang.org/p/v5tBPr-JdKu

Comment: I've found that I run into questions like these pretty often so I'm starting to keep bench results at https://github.com/MacroPower/marshal-bench-go

From this, going from map/struct to json (marshaling) is very similar. In fact, it looks like using maps is very slightly better for memory.

However, going from json to map/struct (unmarshaling) is quite different. Using maps here is quite a bit worse, especially for memory with B/op being 3x worse than using structs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My though is that using Struct is better since the types of the fields are defined. If you use map then it's obviously you'll use map[string]interface{} since the values will vary. Using interfaces typed data will allocate heap memories. Since you're just returning response then it's better to use struct with defined types to reduce run time checking for the types. The performance difference is not significance tho.